# Why have a return keyword if you're not returning a value?

Tags: java, return, void

As I was reading my AP java book I stumbled upon this section that made no sense to me:

...The getBalance method simply returns the current balance. A return statement obtains the value of a variable and exits the method immediately. The return value becomes the value of the method call expression. The syntax of a return statement is:

```
return expression;
```

or

```
return; // Exits the method without sending back a value
```

Why would you want to have a return statement and "exit the method without sending back a value" if you could just make it void?

***Note: Sorry if this may be too subjective. I just couldn't understand the point and the book doesn't explain it.

Comment: What do you mean? The method must already be `void` if it contains a statement such as `return;`. The `return` statement without any argument is only allowed in void methods (and constructors).

Comment: @arshajii I thought a method cant be void if it has "return" after all void means that method returns no value.

Comment: When you use the argument-less `return` statement in a void method you don't return anything, you just end the method.

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of subjective.  I'm old school, I believe in one entry and exit point for all methods/functions, but...

If you have a method with a `void` return type and if you had reached a point in your logic which would dictate that no further processing should take place, you could call `return;` to force the execution to return to the calling method at this point, foregoing any further execution of the method.

It would be the same as using something like `return x;` in the middle of a method body that had an expected return type (of whatever `x` is)

It's a little like using `break` to break out of a `loop` prematurely, except you're breaking out of the method before the execution gets to the end.

Answer (score 3):

The `return` keyword doesn't need to be at the end. For example:

```
public static void print42(int[] numbers) {
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == 42) {
            System.out.println("has 42");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("no 42");
}
```

It can't just use a `break`, as that would print both strings.

Answer (score 2):

There are some situations where once you've verified something inside a `void` function, it makes sense to exit it immediately. For example:

```
public static void checkIfStringInList(List<String> searchList, String findString) {
    for( String thisSearchString : searchList ) {
        if( findString.equals(thisSearchString) )
            return;
    }

    throw new Exception("String " + findString + " not found in list");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A method declared as `void` can exit with a `return;` this is just a shortcut for early termination. A method with a non-`void` return type *must* return a value of the right type, you can not have a method return "nothing" if it has a non-`void` return type.

Answer (score 1):

If your method has a `void` return type, then the `return` statement is optional.  You might want to use it anyway if, for instance, you wanted to stop execution in certain cases.

If the return type is *not* void, then using `return;` without an argument will give you a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

In java if a method has a return type in its signature, you must return an object of that type or null before exiting the method.

for example

```
    public A foo(boolean val){

    A obj=null;
    if (val){
    obj=new A();
    obj.setSomeAttribute();
    }
   return obj;


    }
```

You can not compile source code if you just code "return;"

Comment: Return type, not return class.  It's an important distinction.  Also, you can legally return `null` in place of an object.